# Not able to make connection from jenkins to AWS ec2 servers

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use SSH plugins in Jenkins to execute the script on the remote host server. I have added the remote user credentials on Jenkins but not able to make the connection on AWS ec2 instance.

screenshot of the error:

[image]

Am I missing any steps while doing the configurations? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider

- Does the Security Group on the Target `3.56.98.1` allow for SSH
  access from the Jenkins IP address?
- Do you have the Public SSH Key of Jenkins added to the targets authorised keys file?
- Have you set the correct username that Jenkins will use in the target `ubuntu, ec2-user, other`?

Comment: Yes. All the points mentioned above have been set up perfectly but still not able to connect to the ec2 server through Jenkins ssh plugins.

Comment: Can you get a detail error? SSH into the jenkins and try to SSH to the target instance with -vvv flag